# Customize validation for HTML input

Tags: php, html, laravel, validation

I want to allow same HTML tags like `<img> <strong> <p>` to be usable by site users, but how to check misusing these tags, such as unclosed `<p>` that can match by a closing `</p>` in site theme and make page corrupted? also, I make shorten long posts for showing on index page that can make broken tags too.

Laravel has a `csrf-token` tag for preventing cross-site scripts, but doesn't seem to check things i said.

Comment: Write a validation for confirm closing tags on save.

Comment: @Bira Any internal function in PHP or Laravel for this?

Comment: You can check html is valid using f.e. [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.validate.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the laravelish way for this issue, but you could write your own validation function using regular expressions. Here's a demo for `p` tags:

```
// Html code here
$html = 'here'; 

// Strip newlines so we won't need multilines modifiers
$html = str_replace("\r\n", "", $html);

// Strip correct <p>...</p> tags and their content from html data
$html = preg_replace("@<p>.*?</p>@", "", $html);

// Check if any <p> tag remains in data. If so, it means a tag has been unenclosed/enclosed incorrectly
$s[0] = strpos($html, '<p>');
$s[1] = strpos($html, '</p>');

if($s[0] !== false || $s[1] !== false)
    echo "Syntax error in HTML code";
```